# Make geographic squares that follow parallels in SQL Server

Tags: sql, geography-data-type

I have a list of points (with latitude and longitude) in an SQL Server database, and for each of these points I have to generate a 50 x 50 degrees square (the point being the South West angle of the square).

For instance, if I have the point `0,0` I create the polygon with the following SQL query:

`SELECT geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50, 0 0))', 4326)`

I expected that any point with a latitude greater than 50 would not be part of the polygon generated above. But if I check if the point `25,52` is within the polygon, the query returns `true`

`SELECT geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50, 0 0))', 4326).STIntersects(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(25 52)', 4326))` -> true

The reason is because when I display the polygon, the shape is rounded at the top:

[image: The 50x50 polygon]

In this case, how can I generate a geographic polygon where the upper edge is straight and follow the 50th parallel? Should I use another projection?

Also Geometry data type is not an option for this project, I need to stick to Geography.

Comment: A "square" on the globe isn't square. Your chosen datatype does not allow simple Cartesian operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it with regular `Polygon`, but you need to add a lot of points along the parallel to reduce error.

Or you can use `CURVEPOLYGON` with `CIRCULARSTRING` that follows exactly the parallel (but might be slower and less portable to other systems).